# Generalization of IMO5 from 1987

Tags: euclidean-geometry, gm.general-mathematics

The following question appeared as question 5 on the IMO in 1987:

Prove that for all $n \geq 3$ one can find $n$ distinct points on the Euclidean plane with the property that the distance between any two is irrational and the area of any three is rational.

The answer is given by the points $P_k = (k, k^2)$ with $1 \leq k \leq n$, say. It is pretty easy to see that such a set does indeed satisfy the conditions required in the problem.

My question is: how does one characterize the sets with this property?

Comment: What makes you think there is any reasonable characterization of those? Most sets of lattice points will have this property (they will all have rational areas, and usually the distances will be irrational), but these are surely not the only ones, as most affine transforms of such set will also have that property.

Comment: If area is defined as I think it is, $P_k = (0, ak)$ for any irrational $a$ also works, so it's not necessary to use rational lattice points.

Comment: Perhaps, at the start, one should forget about any assumption about the distances, one should simply characterize the rational areas. #### Only then, one should do just the opposite characterizations, when *adding the restriction* on the distances. Then we get the needed or generalized characterization as a logical difference: triangles such that the area is rational while the distances fail the respective condition on the distances.